# the module is not installed

Tags: git, npm

I do this command:

```
 npm install --save @ng-select/ng-select
```

and I obtain thiss exception:

```
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! undefined ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/angular/cdk-builds.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! undefined
npm ERR! No git binary found in $PATH
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\franc\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-12-09T17_06_39_769Z-debug.log
```

I have just intalled git and I put it in my path variable  `C:\Program Files\Git\bin`. what is the problem?

Comment: When u installed git have u added it to the path? you choose it during the installation

Answer (score 1):

Looks like git is not installed in your path, You can set it during the windows installation.

To verify that this is the problem open Git-bash and execute the command from the bash

---

#### How to verify that git is in your path?

run `git --version` and verify that git is found